# Encrypt AWS keys on local machine for AWS commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, password-encryption, secret-key

On developers machines, when using `aws --configure` and `s3cmd configure`, the AWS key and secret are stored in a plain text file.

For security reasons I'd like the secret, at least, to be kept in a secure and encrypted way, using MAC keychain for example.

Env variables don't seem like a solution as they would also need to be kept securely.

Is there any way to store the keys in a secure way?

(As a side note, no need to mention that all machines have passwords and the keys have the minimum needed permissions in AWS and there are other security methods in place.)

Comment: What is the threat vector that you're trying to secure against?

Comment: Stealing keys, the same reason as you store passwords encrypted

Comment: Who steals those keys? Are you concerned about someone losing their laptop, or about a person inside your company that sees an unattended laptop and cats the config file? Or something else?

Comment: My point is that, depending on the vector, you may want to take different approaches to security. For example, is it reasonable to require your developers to hit a website to get security credentials for their session? How about if those credentials only last an hour?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of long-term credentials (AWS IAM Access Keys), you can use **short-term credentials** by leveraging AWS SSO & AWS Organizations. The short-term credentials are not encrypted though, but temporarily valid (can be configured).

see https://latanassov.dev/aws/2020-01-23/aws-sso-aws-cli.html

Comment: the link is down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the `credential_process` key in my `~/.aws/config` file as a way to achieve this. You set it to a command to run that will print the credentials to `stdout`. I'm using a bash script around `pass`, but you can use whatever you want.

For example, we'll configure a profile `simonw` by setting this in `~/.aws/config`

```
[profile simonw]
credential_process = get-my-creds-cmd
output = json
```

...then we need that `get-my-creds-cmd` command to exist on the `$PATH`, or you can reference it with an absolute path. We'll create the command as a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
accessKey=AKIA...  # TODO get this from somewhere secure
secretKey=...      # TODO get this from somewhere secure

cat << HEREDOC
{
  "Version": 1,
  "AccessKeyId": "$accessKey",
  "SecretAccessKey": "$secretKey"
}
HEREDOC
```

Make sure that bash script is on the `$PATH` and `chmod +x` it so it can be executed.

Now we can test it works

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --profile simonw
```

If you implemented the bash script to read MAC Keychain, you might get prompted for a password to unlock the keychain.

I got this idea from [this blog](https://ben11kehoe.medium.com/never-put-aws-temporary-credentials-in-env-vars-or-credentials-files-theres-a-better-way-25ec45b4d73e). Also, here's the [official AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sourcing-external.html).